# why should we disable animation in protractor?

Tags: protractor

I have come across many forums explaining on how to disable animation while setting up protractor tests. I am not able to figure out why do we need to do this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling animation improve performance of tests and make them run faster. Animations are just eye candy stuff and shouldn't impact on the application logic. They are not needed in this development step.